# Access workspace path in XCode Build Phases script

Tags: xcodebuild, xcode-workspace

In XCode, I'm building a Build Phases script in which I need to call `xcodebuild` with a workspace as parameter.

I know how to get a project's path (`PROJECT_FILE_PATH`), but I can't find a way to find the workspace's path.

For now I'm using a trick to change the extension of project's path from `.xcproject` to `.xcworkspace` :

`WORKSPACE_FILE_PATH="${PROJECT_FILE_PATH%.*}.xcworkspace"`

But I'd rather use a better solution.

Anyone got a clue ?

Answer (score 2):

Usually, the workspace file is in the same directory as the project file, so you can just do it that way.